# Attempts to control offset of UIBarButtonItem title in UIToolbar are failing

Tags: iphone, ios, uibarbuttonitem

The button is declared as a property (via the storyboard) in the view controller's header file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *settingsButton;
```

And set up like so in the implementation:

```
self.settingsButton.title = @"⚙";
[self.settingsButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24.0], NSFontAttributeName,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.settingsButton setTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 5.0f) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

However, the offset settings just don't do anything at all. No matter what I change the values to, the button just sits slightly too high in the UIToolbar like it always has.